# Can the zoom/scale on JS Grid conrol in gantt mode be changed?

Tags: 2010, development, gantt-view

I have created a webpart with a JS Grid control with gantt enabled.
I want the gantt view to display months instead of weekdays.
Anyone have an idea how to do this?

Update:
The following link is what I used to create the gantt webpart.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407962.aspx
What I need is to zoom out gantt.

I have found SetZoomLevelInternal and SetZoomLevel in JsGrid.Gantt.js but cant see how to get it working.

Comment: Is this a third-party gantt control?  If so, can you send a link to it for us to take a look at?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535898.aspx

Comment: Does anybody know how to change the width of each row in Gantt chart?

Answer (score 4):

Combining [SharePoint 2010 – Autozoom Gantt Chart Web Part](http://www.sharepoint-howto.com/2011/12/15/sharepoint-2010-autozoom-gantt-chart/) with my own code, i get this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">
// By Cees Timmerman, 24oct12.
$(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("th[title='Title']").css({"width":"400px"})
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) WebPartWPQ2_JSGridController.ZoomOutGantt()
  }, 2000)
})</script>
```

Put that in a Content Editor's HTML source and enjoy.

If you want to get all fancy, try [this](http://tomblog.insomniacminds.com/2011/07/09/sharepoint-2010-customizing-the-gantt-view-and-the-client-grid/#comment-56437):

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
  var oldGanttControl = SP.GanttControl
  SP.GanttControl = function(){
    oldGanttControl.call(this)
    var oldInit = this.Init
    this.Init = function(jsGridControl, jsRawGridData, params){
      oldInit.call(this, jsGridControl, jsRawGridData, params)
      DoCustomizations(jsGridControl)
    }
  }
}, "SPGantt.js")
function DoCustomizations(grid){
  grid.SetSplitterPosition(800)
  grid.SetGanttZoomLevel(grid.GetGanttZoomLevel()-1)
  var columns = grid.GetColumns()
  $.each(columns, function(key, value){value.width=200})
  grid.UpdateColumns(grid.parentNode.jsgridtableviewparams.columns)
}
```

Comment: Will the 1st script work with OOB Gantt Chart view?

Comment: If you can correct the zoomOut function, it will work with the default Gantt chart.

Answer (score 0):

for displaying months in gantt view. I did little modifications to fancy thing above.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
  var oldGanttControl = SP.GanttControl
  SP.GanttControl = function(){
    oldGanttControl.call(this)
    var oldInit = this.Init
    this.Init = function(jsGridControl, jsRawGridData, params){
      oldInit.call(this, jsGridControl, jsRawGridData, params)
      DoCustomizations()
    }
  }
}, "SPGantt.js")
function DoCustomizations(){
    WebPartWPQ2_JSGridController.ZoomOutGantt();
    WebPartWPQ2_JSGridController.ZoomOutGantt();
}</script>
```